# What is the name of the grammatical construction "noun + present participle", i.e. a noun phrase followed by a participle?

Tags: grammar

What is the name of the grammatical construction "noun + present participle", i.e. a noun phrase followed by a participle as in the sentence "His panic fading now that there was no sound of Filch and Snape, Harry moved nearer to the mirror, wanting to look at himself but seeing no reflection again."?

The noun I'm referring to is "panic" and the participle is "fading".

Well, I already know the answer it's nominative absolute which was appropriately pointed out by KarlG and the credit goes to him. I looked it up to further clear things out.

What I gathered is the absolute phrase only describes the circumstances of the main clause. The participle modifies the subject of the absolute phrase. And as I understand, correct me if I'm wrong, the present participle as a part of the absolute phrase doesn't imply any ongoing action.

So, the sentence in question can be rewritten, without any change in meaning, in the following manner: "When his panic faded now that there was no sound of Filch and Snape, Harry moved nearer to the mirror, wanting to look at himself but seeing no reflection again."

Comment: The "..." suggests that what you're calling a sentence is actually a sentence fragment. It may seem strange or ungrammatical out of context. It will be hard to give you a definite expert answer without the context.

Comment: Possibly the complete sentence is: "His panic fading now that there was no sound of Filch and Snape, Harry moved nearer to the mirror, wanting to look at himself but seeing no reflection again." (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Comment: @KarlG Please use comments only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Do not use comments to answer (post an [answer](/help/how-to-answer) instead). Note that an answer which consists of barely more than a link is not useful and may be removed even if it is correct. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @MetaEd: Actually, I posted the link after the question was closed because I didn't want the OP to go away empty-handed. It was clear the question was about an absolute construction. Thanks for making this stack such a welcoming place.

Comment: @KarlG Answers in comments are not necessarily unwelcome. When a question is definitely on track to be deleted, a comment providing some helpful information to the asker is fine. When a question is closed because it's unclear or lacks research, that shouldn't be taken to mean the question is on track to be deleted. In that case the best thing is to wait for the asker to clarify or update the question.

Comment: @MetaEd: I meant welcoming to first posters. You put a question on hold that's obviously about nominative absolutes. How is someone who thinks _fading_ is somehow a noun going to "research" that question? So I post a link, which then disappears, replaced by a lecture. Thus the OP now knows far more about your interpretation of site guidelines than absolute constructions.

Comment: @KarlG Actually, I was referring to "panic" as the noun in that sentence. However, it's true that I had no idea as to what the nominative absolute is. I tried to research but without knowing the name of what I was trying to research it brought no results.

Comment: @Andrey: And that's the reason I objected to the hold.

Comment: The question is reopened. Thanks for providing the context.

Comment: @KarlG To make first posters welcome, we communicate with them respectfully, and we help them learn to use the site. As an experienced user, you can help in your interactions with first posters by following site guidelines. That's how they learn what is expected of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A participle in an [*absolute construction*](https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049)

- always has a subject
- relates to an entire clause or action
- stands in no clear grammatical relationship to another element in the
  sentence.

A present participle in an absolute, as in your example, describes an action/state more or less simultaneous to the one in the main clause:

> The train came to an abrupt halt, the locomotive's brakes [*screeching*](https://books.google.de/books?id=-A4bBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT43&dq=%22our+car+shaking+from%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXotOzrqHbAhUNalAKHZkVCycQ6AEIJDAA) loudly, our car *shaking* from the impact of one carriage crushing into another. — Wolfgang W. E. Samuel, *German Boy: A Refugee’s Story*, 2009.
>
> Melinda sat sideways, [*her legs dangling*](https://books.google.de/books?id=yyYiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT77&dq=%22her+legs+dangling%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcj9LasKHbAhWCCuwKHc0eDp0Q6AEIQzAF) out the door of the SUV while she ate the meal her mom had brought her. — Chantilly White, *Snow Angel*, 2014.
>
> The storm [*unrelenting*](https://books.google.de/books?id=cXnyAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=%22the+storm+unrelenting,+he%22&source=bl&ots=IdbdbZJIHd&sig=P6l8cKb-G5INt3Av60cWz2DrDIs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCvdSZtKHbAhUHDewKHZPqCB4Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ), he called them, “Gotta check on you two. Want me to drive down to help? Sure, I was there earlier today, but you two are more than worth a second visit in the same day.”  — Mark Henry Miller, *Murder in the Chapel*, 2013.

A perfect participle indicates a prior action in the past, analogous to the past perfect in standard past-tense narration:

> The holiday was full of adventure; I remember hearing my mother whispering the Lord’s Prayer as we crawled along the cliff road in search of a garage, our [*car having developed*](https://books.google.de/books?id=AglE9rxa0rYC&pg=PA252&dq=%22our+car+having+developed%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYxJXrq6HbAhXByqQKHc8UDAoQuwUIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22our%20car%20having%20developed%22&f=false) a serious mechanical problem with the axle. — Lee Arbouin, *The Nottingham Connection*, 2012, 252.
>
> The road extends from Erie to the Michigan-Ohio line and the inspection was made preparatory to work the coming summer, the [*road having been* recently *taken over*](https://books.google.de/books?id=BokfAQAAMAAJ&q=%22road+having+been+recently%22&dq=%22road+having+been+recently%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4zMy5wKHbAhVG46QKHWwSB6gQ6AEIMzAC) by the county.  — *Michigan Roads and Construction*, vol. 22 (1925),150.

A past participle in an absolute occasionally cues an action or state already completed:

> The [*battle won*](https://books.google.de/books?id=AsooBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT2&dq=%22the+battle+won+again+he%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1hpnRxqHbAhVNKVAKHa2qDIkQ6AEIJDAA) again, he dove under his bedcovers and waited whilst she tucked him in.  — Aldrea Alien, *The Rogue King*,  2014.

But most of the time, it is descriptive background:

> The American flag hanging from a pole in the interior clapped sharply with every gust of wind, its [*colors muted*](https://books.google.de/books?id=x-McDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&dq=%22its+colors+muted%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0mcedw6HbAhWPaVAKHQsTB3kQ6AEIWDAJ) gray in the faint light. — Jordanna Max Brodsky, *Winter of the Gods*, 2017.
>
> Then as he racked his memory, he heard the sharp crackling of a fusillade; he saw a standard fall before him, its [*staff broken*](https://books.google.de/books?id=eRaGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT365&dq=%22its+staff+broken%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQy8-yxKHbAhXQKVAKHedFDQUQ6AEISzAH) and its folds drooping like the wings of a bird brought down by a shot. — Emile Zola, *The Fortune Of The Rougons*, 2016.
>
> The memories were banished and he was left in the dark bedroom, standing near the prince's bed, the [*silence broken*](https://books.google.de/books?id=mryWBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA264&dq=%22the+silence+broken%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ8-qbxaHbAhUJJVAKHZDWC2UQ6AEIMzAD) by his thoughtless murmur. — Ash Stinson, *The Broken Soldier*, 2014, 264.

If the participle is a form of *to be*, it is frequently omitted, leaving it to the reader to supply *being* or *having been* according to context.

> The [*journey finally over*](https://books.google.de/books?id=vADNBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT34&dq=%22journey+finally+over,+we%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI5fDyvqHbAhXMjqQKHSnwCKgQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22journey%20finally%20over%2C%20we%22&f=false), we were washed up on the shore of day, given sweet orange juice to drink and shood gently on our way by a silent person in a Green Man Mask.

Answer (score -1):

> His panic fading now that there was no sound of Filch and Snape, Harry moved nearer to the mirror, wanting to look at himself but seeing no reflection again.

The present participle *fading* does indicate (not just implies) *ongoing action*, as does *wanting*. Both *ing forms* show *ongoing action*. The "circumstance" that the absolute clause shows can be ongoing. On the other hand, using *faded* instead of *fading* one shows that the action has stopped.